# store locally either in asyncStorage or in a state

Tags: react-native, redux

I use redux for state management. Now I have a json object of 1000 objects that I need to store locally either in asyncStorage or in a state to use it in different part of my application. What is the best way to handle this json data

```
const initialState = {
  loading: false,
  dataAppDB:{}
}
```

```
            try {

              await fetch(url)
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => {
                 
                  thunkAPI.dispatch(saveDataApp(data));
                  
                  let data1 = JSON.stringify(data);
                  AsyncStorage.setItem('dataAppDB', data1);
                  
                });
            } catch (e) {

              }
            
            }

          }
```

Is it normal to store these 1000 json objects in for example in state : dataAppDB = {}
and to be able to use it in my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will depend on one simple question. Do you need the data to persist after the app was closed?

If yes, then using AsyncStorage is a valid approach. Of course, you can also have a proper backend with a database, but AsyncStorage will do the job.

If not, then what you want is to use a context, for this you have different options. A common one is the hook useContext, but redux is also a very good alternative.

Comment: Yes I would like the data to persist if the application closes. But the most important question for me is if asynchroneStorage can take these 1000 json objects for me to reuse as needed without problem

Comment: yes, it can, you will need to check the performance of it, but I think 1000 shouldn't be an issue.